# When the last class is hidden, A message will be shown

Tags: jquery

I have a message along with other classes, `.tab` inside a parent div.

**Goal**: When I click on a `.tab`, it will hide and after a last tab is clicked, the message will show up.

**Problem**: When the first tab is clicked, the message shows up right away.

Please take a look at my sample in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrk837uz/)

Code:

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  if (!$('#banner-message').hasClass('tab')) {
    $('.message').show();
  }
})
```

```css
#banner-message {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 42px;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span class="message">
      This is a banner message
      </span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab1</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab2</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The `banner-message` element doesn't have the `tab` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `if` logic is not correct, since you are checking:

```
!$('#banner-message').hasClass('tab')
```

which means: If element with id `banner-message` doesn't have class `tab`, then do something...

One solution is to check if the amount of visible `.tab` elements is 0.

You can do it by using the jQuery selector: `$(".tab:visible")`, this will get all elements with class `tab` that are visible, so if this equals to 0, show the message.

See below:

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  if ($('.tab:visible').length == 0) {
    $('.message').show();
  }
})
```

```css
#banner-message {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 42px;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span class="message">
   This is a banner message
  </span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab1</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab2</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hehehe for just a couple of seconds... but anyway, I'll upvote you :D

Comment: Thanks Jayesh Goyani, Twisty and Calvin Nunes a lot to share not only one solution, but many! Every solution here is absolutely acceptable and appreciated.  So, I upvoted all solutions and accepted one with detail explanations.  Also, can you please show me how to set up for `run code snippet` right on this page.  Thanks

Comment: to setup a runnable snippet, when adding or editing an answer/question, look for the button that looks like `<>` on the toolbar, click it and you'll be able to create a snippet

Answer (score 2):

You just need a better logical condition. If the number of visible tabs is 0, then show the message.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tab').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    if ($(".tab:visible").length == 0) {
      $("#banner-message .message").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#banner-message {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 42px;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span class="message">
      This is a banner message
      </span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab1</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab2</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

JS

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  if($(".tab").is(":visible") == false) { 
    $('.message').show();
  }
})
```

I have modified if condition so it will show  message when all tabs will be hide.